# In function `_start': undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld

I am working on a project that has more than 30 source files and some sub dirs> 
I added the i2c support and I am trying to compile it but I got the following errors:

```
=== Making Control Interface Type.
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/i2c_test/TestBench/interfaces'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -g -O0 -std=c11 -DWIN32 -DUSE_SPIDEV -    D_DEFAULT_SOURCE   -c -o i2cdev_lib.o i2cdev_lib.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -g -O0 -std=c11 -DWIN32 -DUSE_SPIDEV -    D_DEFAULT_SOURCE   -c -o spidev_lib.o spidev_lib.c
+++ Compiling I2C_SPI_LIB i2cdev_lib.o spidev_lib.o
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In     function `_start':
/build/glibc-1yTpB4/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119:
undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:56: recipe for target '../Debug/i2c_spidev_lib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../Debug/i2c_spidev_lib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/i2c_test/TestBench/interfaces'
Makefile:139: recipe for target 'interface' failed
```

lines in Makefile
    # Pattern Rules
    $(CIFOUTDIR)/i2c_spidev_lib.o : i2cdev_lib.o spidev_lib.o 
        @echo "+++ Compiling I2C_SPI_LIB $^"
        @$(LD) -o $@ $^

```
$(CIFOUTDIR)/spidev_lib.o : spidev_lib.c # compile directly to restoutdir
    @echo "+++ Compiling $<"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ldl -lgcc -lc -lm -c -o $@ $<

$(CIFOUTDIR)/i2cdev_lib.o : i2cdev_lib.c # compile directly to restoutdir
    @echo "+++ Compiling $<"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ldl -lgcc -lc -lm -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Are you building a *library*? Then you should not link it normally. What you should do differ depending on if you're making a static library or a dynamic library. There are many duplicates here and all over the Internet on how to create both types.

Comment: Linking  `-ldl -lgcc -lc -lm` to an *object file* is meaningless and **wrong**. You need to read much more about [linkers](http://iecc.com/linkers/)

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong rules.  The rules you've presented would not output the observed message "+++ Compiling I2C_SPI_LIB i2cdev_lib.o spidev_lib.o".  They would output something more like "+++ Compiling spidev_lib.c".

Comment: Even doing like that I still get the same error         


    $(CIFOUTDIR)/i2c_spidev_lib.o : i2cdev_lib.c spidev_lib.c # compile directly to restoutdir
         @echo "+++ Compiling I2C_SPI_LIB $^"
         @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ldl -lgcc -lc -lm -o $@ $?

Comment: Can you please verify that your project contains at least one file having a function name `main() { }`. It doesn't matter even if the function doesn't contain anything. But it is necessary that there must be a function with name "main()".
Because the `startup.S` file is complaining about it. There should be a code to jump to `main` function in `startup.S` under the label `__start:` something like `b main` i.e. branch to main.